# Ubuntu: Modprobe on startup

Tags: ubuntu, modprobe

First, this is strange. I have two laptops running Ubuntu 10.10. On one of them, when connecting my 3G modem, it just works out of the box. For the other one, I need to `modprobe option` to register it as a GSM modem.

How can I do this at boot?

Answer (score 3):

Add a line to /etc/modules that just reads "option".

Comment: Note this might not work if the hardware is not present on boot and you might have to still run your `modprobe option` if you insert the card after boot.

Comment: Thanks! But what can I do to ensure it to be automatically recognized if inserted after booting? On my second laptop it works perfectly well without explicit modprobe.

Comment: Before I speculate, can you verify that that doing this still does NOT work when inserting the modem later? Like I said, it MIGHT work. It's not clear what's wrong with your bus/hotswap/notification/detection systems, but it might be that having the module loaded ahead of time does the job when the devices shows up.